# Does name on green card need to be changed before applying for citizenship?

Tags: usa, citizenship, greencard

My wife has a green card and is trying to apply for US citizenship. Her green card lists her maiden name but she changed it after we got married. Does she need to get her green card changed before she applies for citizenship?

Comment: Did she apply for her green card before or after marriage? If after marriage, shouldn't her green card already have her married name?

Comment: I don't think it matters for naturalization per se, but the green card should reflect her current name regardless, being it an ID and such

Comment: @user102008, she got her green card before we met.

Comment: @littleadv: I believe an ID with an old name can be used in combination with the name change order, as an ID for the new name

Comment: Sure, maybe. Saves a fee at the expense of a border guard of airline clerk not knowing what to do and getting stuck.

Comment: @littleadv if the ticket is booked with the previous name there would be no trouble.  If the ticket is booked with the new name then there might be some delay with the airline clerk but there shouldn't be with the border guard; they aren't necessarily even aware of the current name, and if they are they surely either know how to handle it or can look it up in a policy manual.  The policy is available to the public at https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1209